# How to get axis aligned bounding box of convex bodies

Tags: drake

I'd like to set the position of some convex bodies such that the body is flush against a ground plane.

To do so, I want to calculate the axis aligned bounding box so I can use the lowest point on the body.

I am adding convex bodies like this:

```
            cv_shape = Convex(str(ROOT_PATH / mesh_path_list[body_idx]), scale=scale_factors[body_idx])

            name = f"polytope_{body_idx}"
            instance =self.plant.AddModelInstance(name)
            H = RigidTransform(RotationMatrix(np.eye(3)), np.zeros(3))

            body = self.plant.AddRigidBody(
                name, instance,
                SpatialInertia(mass=m,
                               p_PScm_E=np.array([0., 0., 0.]),
                               G_SP_E=inertia))
            geom_id = self.plant.RegisterCollisionGeometry(
                body, H,
                cv_shape, name,
                pydrake.multibody.plant.CoulombFriction(mu, mu))
```

How to get the AABB?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to Drake issue [#18421](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/18421). A user had specifically requested an Obb for the mesh in place of the Aabb. I believe that user had obtained the Aabb by directly [reading the obj in as a `SurfaceTriangleMesh`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/namespacedrake_1_1geometry.html#a4192d45a6ef62766081175664984a770) and then [asking the mesh for its axis-aligned box](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_triangle_surface_mesh.html#a972cf7cd80fb7a8357c8202a6c163612). That issue will be resolved soon and we'll provide access for Aabb and Obb for shapes more generally via more public APIs.